# angular 2 login flow with localStorage and http api call

Tags: angular, api, angular-promise, angular2-localstorage

im pretty new to angular 2 and im currently trying to get my login flow done. Im posting user credentials to api and receive jwt token. then i request user details with this token and store all the information in localStorage, but im not sure if its the right way, sometimes i have problems.

login method

```
  login(user): Promise<any> {
localStorage.clear();
return this.http
  .post(`${this.url}/auth/login_check`, JSON.stringify(user), { headers: this.headers }).toPromise().then(resp => {
    let json = resp.json();
      if (json.token){
        console.log('token exists')
        localStorage.setItem('jwt_token', json.token);
        this.storeUser().then(resp => {
          console.log('user exists')
          return true;
        }, err => {
          this.handleError(err);
          return false;
        })
      }
      else {
        return false;
      }
    },
    err => {
      this.handleError(err);
      return false;
    })
  };
```

storeUser method

```
  storeUser(): Promise<any> {
this.headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer '+localStorage.getItem('jwt_token'));
console.log(this.headers);
return this.http.get(`${this.url}/users/0`, { headers: this.headers }).toPromise().then(resp => {
  let json = resp.json();

  let picture = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,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';

  localStorage.setItem('user_id', json.id);
  localStorage.setItem('user_username', json.username);
  localStorage.setItem('user_email', json.email);
  localStorage.setItem('user_enabled', json.enabled);
  localStorage.setItem('user_last_login', json.last_login);
  localStorage.setItem('user_roles', json.roles);
  localStorage.setItem('user_validated', json.validated);
  localStorage.setItem('user_picture', picture);
  console.log(localStorage.getItem('user_username'));
  return true;
},
err => {
  this.handleError(err);
  return false;
});
```

}

signIn Method in login component

```
  signIn() {
this.processing = true;
this.active = true;
this.error = false;
this.success = false;

this.authSvc.login({ username: this.loginForm.value['username'], password: this.loginForm.value['password'] }).then(resp => {

  this.processing = false;
  this.success = true;
  this.router.navigateByUrl('');
}, err => {
  this.processing = false;
  this.error = true;
})
```

};

Comment: What problems do you face? please specify.

Comment: at first im not sure if this is the right way in 1. the way i use the promises, 2. if theres a better way to handle errors or to write less code.
besides that im not sure if localStore is used correctly either (because its synchronous?)

Comment: about local storage i would suggest you to store the data as an entire object rather than storing it as single values, since all the data is user related. 
If you want to try different login approach then you can try observables.

Comment: "sometimes i have problems" please clarify your problem so we can help you out. Read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask